# mkdir doesn't do path expansion

Tags: bash

So I have folder `aa`

```
$ mkdir aa
```

and path expansion for `ls` command works like this:

```
$ ls -la a*
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 a a 0 Mar 29 08:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 a a 0 Dec 31  1979 ../
$ ls -la a?
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 a a 0 Mar 29 08:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 a a 0 Dec 31  1979 ../
```

But "the same" for mkdir shows an error:

```
$ mkdir a*/bb
mkdir: cannot create directory 'a*/bb': No such file or directory
$ mkdir a?/bb
mkdir: cannot create directory 'a?/bb': No such file or directory
```

Where can I read why this difference in behavior happens and is there simple trick to let mkdir be "smarter" for behavior like in ls?

Comment: if first example you have the asterics at ls in the second in mkdir?

Comment: I've edited the question to split first mkdir , hope it is not confusing anymore

Comment: So what you want with the Statement is to create Directory `aa` in every subdirectory starting with a?

Comment: Basically I wanted a* and a? to just expand and pfnuesel confirmed why it doesn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work, since wildcard expansion is done before the argument is passed to `mkdir`. `bash` tries to expand `a*/bb`, doesn't find a match and tells you so. `mkdir` is not even invoked here. You can also try e.g.

```
echo a*/bb
```

or as you did before

```
ls -la a*/bb
```

Both commands will give you the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Now I realize how stupid that question was. Probably I wanted something like this for expansion to work:

```
mkdir "$(ls -d a?)"/bb
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
mkdir -p a*/aa
mkdir -p a?/aa
```

Comment: that silently doesn't create any folder

Comment: or rather creates a* folder, where I wanted a* to expand to existing folder aa. Anyway, thank you - i have accepted another answer which confirms reasons of actual behavior - bash only expands full path, doesn't do expansion of parts of path